# Resizing window to a particular size

Tags: unity, 15.04, wmctrl

I want to resize a game's window to 1280x720. I tried with wctrl and xdotools but it wasn't working. I'm using 15.04.

[Here's](https://youtu.be/8_bKUW32pgU) a video showing the problem.

Comment: What you have already tried. Post the details in your question.

Comment: Also: are you on Unity?

Comment: Yes, Unity and 15.04

Comment: A  question: it seems an options-menu window, which could very well be of a fixed size. Can you resize it manually? if not, `wmctrl` also will not be able to.

Comment: Yes, I can resize it manually.

Comment: You are using the window-id, but not the option `-i` in the command. Change it to `wmctrl -ir <window_id> -e 0,0,0,1280,720`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use the -i flag if you run the resize-command with the window's id

Looking at your Youtube movie, it occurred to me that you are using the command:

```
wmctrl -r <window_id> -e 0,0,0,1280,720
```

You can use the command like that when you use a *windowname* as identifictaion. If you however use the *window-id*, looking like `0x02c00042`, you need to use the `-i` flag to make it work.

The command should then be:

```
wmctrl -ir <window_id> -e 0,0,0,1280,720
```

#### Why didn't the command work using the window *name*

In the same movie, you first tried with the command:

```
wmctrl -r <window_name> -e 0,0,0,1280,720
```

The command actually *did* work...

...but not on the window you were targeting at. If you look closely into the window list, there is another window with the string `Minecraft` in its name: `~/Documents/Minecraft`. This window is higher up in the list, and minimized.

The command `wmctrl -r <window_name> -e 0,0,0,1280,720` *does* resize that window, but since it is still minimized, you didn't notice the difference. The command does not change a window's state from minimized to normal.